# Set velocity at position?

Tags: unity, physics, mathematics, vector

In Unity3D there's a way to add force at a position and a way to get the velocity at a position. I'd like to  be able to set the velocity of a rigidbody2d at a local position.

My current solution which is very much WIP and very much wrong is as follows:

```
            _colliderRigidbody.velocity = _knockbackForce;

            Vector2 dirToCenter = (_colliderRigidbody.position - Position2D).normalized;

            float relativeAngleVel = Vector3.Dot(dirToCenter.normalized, _knockbackForce.normalized);
            bool onRight = Vector3.Cross(dirToCenter, _knockbackForce).z > 0;

            relativeAngleVel = 1.0f - Mathf.Abs(relativeAngleVel);

            relativeAngleVel = onRight ? -relativeAngleVel : relativeAngleVel;

            _colliderRigidbody.angularVelocity = -relativeAngleVel * 50;//lol * 50 because who knows what I'm doing >.<
```

In regards to the problem I'm trying to solve: I have a 'bullet' which hits a target object, I know the point of impact and the direction the bullet is going so I'd like the velocity at that point of impact to be the same as the bullets.

Comment: Can you give us more information about how you intend to apply this? There are two components that contribute to the velocity of a point on the object: its linear velocity and its angular velocity. For any given value of one, we can produce a compensating value for the other so that the net veliocity at that point is the target value. That means the system is under-determined: we have an infinite variety of possible solutions, so we'll need additional criteria to figure out what combination of linear and angular velocity is appropriate for the case in your game.

Comment: @DMGregory Fair point, I added some more info.

Comment: The application you describe would more conventionally use an Impulse. Usually the object you're shooting has a different mass than the bullet, so even with perfect energy transfer it will still get a different velocity to respect conservation of momentum. Is this velocity matching a hard requirement, or can we use a more typical impulse instead?